# How to divide one smoothScatter plot by another?

Tags: r, density-plot

I want to know how common certain place names are. From a national gazetteer, I did two `smoothScatter()` in R, one with all the places, other with the places whose names I'm interested in.

All places:

[image: map 1]

Places with certain names:

[image: map 2]

Now, how can I divide the second by the first, to get the density of the names of interest over all names? It can be a R solution, or ImageMagick, GIMP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick 6, you can divide your two images as follows:

```
convert second.png first.png +swap -compose divide -composite division.png
```

[image]

If using Imagemagick 7, then use magick rather than convert.

Imagemagick 7 is by default compiled in HDRI mode; whereas Imagemagick 6 is not compile in HDRI mode by default.

This means that results can be outside the normal 16-bit range. Thus a division can result in values larger than 1. (See comment below about normalized values used in Imagemagick). However, normally they are clamped to black and white extremes to be able to save to normal image types such as PNG.

But, one can turn clamping off and get the result in a format such as PFM that can save values outside the normal range. Or we can divide by enough that the range is still within the range appropriate to PNG or can stretch the result to full black and white range. So for example:

```
magick second.png first.png +swap -define compose:clamp=off -compose divide -composite -evaluate divide 10 division2.png
```

[image]

```
magick second.png first.png +swap -define compose:clamp=off -compose divide -composite -auto-level division3.png
```

[image]

This gives more detail than the first approach above.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know the meaning of that pink region there?

Comment: Quoting from https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#divide: As normalized color values are used and these normally range from 0.0 (black) to 1.0 (white), division will in fact brighten the numerator image, by the amount of 'black' that appears within the image you are 'dividing by'. So where the divisor channels are dark enough (close to zero), the result will be white (1). But if one or more of the channels of the denominator are not dark enough or are brighter than the same channel in the numerator, then the result in each channel of the result will not be white (1) and so a different color.

Comment: See my additions to my post above.

Comment: There's no true white inside the map. What we have is higher or smaller values in one of the images (dividend/certain names), in relation to the other (divisor/all places). That would give numbers bigger or smaller than 1. Are those that are getting different colors in your last added images? (Since white is #FFFFFF and black is #000000, maybe I should invert the images before dividing?) BTW, I have ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 running on Debian 9.

Comment: My last post is creating values outside the quantum range Q16 (0-65535). Imagemagick does its computations in image space scaled to 0 to 1. But afterwards scales back up by the quantum range. If there is no HDRI, they get clipped. In my last post, I disable the clip, but scaled the max value (among all channels -- not each channel) to white and min (possibly negative values) to black. This avoids the clip and stretches values to fill the dynamic range of the PNG at 16-bits. You get a lot of dark because of the scaling and red, because probably that channel had the largest value.

Comment: IM 6.9.7.4 is old. But Linux distributions do not always upgrade the version number when they patch. The more informative information about the version is actually the version date that you will find when doing  `convert -version`.

Comment: Your version was last patched on Jan 14, 2017, which does conform to the version 6.9.7.4. So over a 1.5 years ago. That should be OK, but you might check to see if there is a more recent patch. Current version is 6.9.10.12.